# Can I hide the dropdown arrows from Data Validation in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, user-interface, data-validation

I use **Data Validation** with `List from a range` set up on all my rows in a column to be able to choose a "Category"

The arrows however, are annoying to see - especially on cells I haven't yet filled.

Is there a way I can hide those arrows and just be able to either start typing or double click in the box to see the options - without ever showing the arrows)

[image: image showing dropdown arrows]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, just un-check the "Show dropdown list in cell" checkbox on the data validation dialog.

[image: data validation settings]